# Assembly read user input doesn't wait

Tags: macos, assembly, input, nasm, wait

I have a assembly program which should write "What's your name?", then wait for user input, and then print "Hello, ". This is my program(Mac, nasm):

```
section .data
 question db "What's your name?"
 answer db "Hello, "
 ln db 10

section .bss
 name resb 16

section .text
global start 
start:
 mov rsi, question
 mov rdi, 17
 call print
 call getName
 mov rsi, answer
 mov rdi, 7
 call print
 mov rsi, ln
 mov rdi, 1
 call print
 mov rax, 0x02000001
 mov rdi, 0
 syscall

print:
 mov rax, 0x02000004
 mov rdi, 1
 syscall
 ret
getName:
 mov rax, 0x02000003
 mov rdi, 0
 mov rsi, name
 mov rdx, 16
 syscall
 ret
```

But this program writes "What's your name?Hello," and only then awaits for user input.
Why doesn't it wait for the input before it writes "Hello,"?

Comment: Isn't your `print` function missing a `mov rdx, rdi` ?

Comment: @Michael No, I set those before calling it so that I don't have to limit the function to one text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mixed up rdx and rdi in start and forgot to print out the name. My bad.
EDIT: For some reason I cannot accept this answer, so: This it the accepted answer!

Comment: You can accept your own answer in a day or two.  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally **wrong**. Register RAX must the value of service syscall. I will help you to correct the code for full program.

compile it with:

*nasm -f elf64 -o objname.o sourcecode.asm*

*ld -m elf_x86_64 -o execname objname.o*

```
%macro print 2
mov rax,1
mov rdi,rax
mov rsi,%1
mov rdx,%2
syscall
%endmacro

%macro getinput 2
mov rax,0
mov rdi,rax
mov rsi,%1
mov rdx,%2
syscall
%endmacro

%macro exit 0
mov rax,60
xor rdi,rdi
syscall
%endmacro

section .data
 question db "What's your name?"
lenques equ $-question
 answer db "Hello, "
lenans equ $-answer
 ln db 10
lenname equ 30

section .bss
 name resb lenname

section .text
global _start
_start:
print question,lenques
push rax
getinput name,lenname
print answer,lenans
pop rbx
print name,rbx
print ln,1
exit
```

Comment: The code in the question *does* set RAX to call numbers that look correct to me for x86-64 MacOS.  They're different from x86-64 Linux, what's why your code needs different numbers.  Remember, asm and system calls aren't portable.

Comment: ow. my mistake. i am not seeing that the question is for mac